# How to display one row at a time ,when i click next display next row in php?

Tags: php

I created a page (exam.php) where I want to show questions one by one.

When a student clicks next after submitting an answer I want it to display the next question.

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['qno']))
        $_SESSION['qno'] = 1;
    else{

        if(isset($_POST['next']))
        {
                $_SESSION['qno'] += 1;
        }

    }


    $sql ="select  * from question where question_id= ' ".$_SESSION['qno']." '  ";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $question =$row['question'];
        $op1 = $row['option1'];
        $op2 = $row['option2'];
        $op3 = $row['option3'];
        $op4 = $row['option4'];


    }

    ?>
```

It works, but in this code I am using question_id to display data. The problem comes after, when admin deletes some questions it is not working due to question_id gap.

I initialize question_id =1; so what is best solution for this problem?

Comment: You should also switch to using the mysqli_ functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LIMIT to pick the question rather than question ID.

```
select * 
from `question`
ORDER BY `question_id`
LIMIT $SESSION[$q_no],1;
```

Comment: ok but how to display next question after submit previous question?

Comment: In the displayed page, or the code which generates it, increment $q_no. To go back, decrement it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must transfer the current id from each page to the next one. you did it by `$_SESSION["qno"]`.

Now you must change your query and run this program:

```
$sql ="select top 1 * from question where question_id>{$_SESSION['qno']} order by question_id";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
  $_SESSION['qno']=$row["question_id"];
  $question =$row['question'];
  $op1 = $row['option1'];
  $op2 = $row['option2'];
  $op3 = $row['option3'];
  $op4 = $row['option4'];
  }
```

Comment: Don't forget voting and accepting as the correct answer.